# Validating digitaly signed PDF Spire.Pdf C#

Tags: c#, pdf, digital-signature

So I am developing a web app that generates a PDF contract from a partial view, and then validates the digital signiture. I came accross an example  [here](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Get-and-Verify-Digital-Signature-in-PDF-with-C-Code.html) . The problem is that an exception is thrown when validating the signiture and for the life of me I cant figure out why...

Here is the code :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {
        ActionResult retVal = View();
        AspNetUser user = DbCtx.AspNetUsers.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        bool signitureIsValid = false;
        string blobUrl = string.Empty;

        if (FileUpload != null && FileUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + RemoveAllSpaces(FileUpload.FileName);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/pdfs"), fileName);

            FileUpload.SaveAs(filePath);

            List<PdfSignature> signatures = new List<PdfSignature>();
            using (var doc = new PdfDocument(filePath))
            {

                var form = (PdfFormWidget) doc.Form;
                int count = 0;
                try
                {
                    count = form.FieldsWidget.Count;
                }
                catch
                {
                    count = 0;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                {
                    var field = form.FieldsWidget[i] as PdfSignatureFieldWidget;
                    if (field != null && field.Signature != null)
                    {
                        PdfSignature signature = field.Signature;
                        signatures.Add(signature);
                    }
                }
            }
            PdfSignature signatureOne = signatures[0]; 
            try
            {
                signitureIsValid = signatureOne.VerifySignature(); // HERE SHE BLOWS !
                if (signitureIsValid)
                {
                    blobPactUrl = await BlobUtil.BasicStorageBlockBlobOperationsAsync(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(blobPactUrl))
                    {
                        ApplicantInfo info = DbCtx.ApplicantInfoes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user.Id);
                        info.URL = blobUrl;
                        info.SignatureIsValid = true;
                        info.ActivationDate = DateTime.Now;
                        info.ActiveUntill = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

                        DbCtx.Entry(info).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        DbCtx.SaveChanges();

                        retVal = RedirectToAction("Publications");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
            }

        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Here is an image of
[what it looks like when I'm debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Qc7.png):

[image]

I have checked the signiture and it is valid and cerified... I know I'm missing something basic here... Please help me internet!

Comment: Yeah, for the appearence and Bounds it is a NullReference but that should not inpact the validation... I think it's cuz of the Certificates prop throwing an ApplicationException and cuz the Certificate prop is null... Witch it shouldn't be...  I first save the fileUpload then I make a PdfDocument object, and the uploaded file is signed and certified so it should bind it...

Comment: what is the exception message?

Comment: Does that happen for all signed PDFs or just some? If the latter, please share an example.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons The Exception that I catch just states that the signiture failed to validate...

Comment: @mkl I have tried it with other signed pdf and the result is the same... It fails validation even tho it is certified and signed.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that I posted this. . . Turns out that the problem was due to bug in the package itself. Upon asking the lovely people at E-Iceblue, the bug was recreated, solved and a new version of Spire.PDF was up on nuget within a week.

great job E-Iceblue, it worked fine :)